# Handle a non existing servlet exception

Tags: java, exception, url, servlets

When I type a non-existing servlet in a url an exception error

```
HTTP Status 404 -
```

that's reasonable, but where should I handle the exception? at what scope??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can automatically deliver a custom 404 page. In your `web.xml` put something like:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```